# How can i use Vue-Lottie in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently working on my Homework with VUE.Js which i found something cool in web which it was using After Effect animation in projects. so here's my question, How should i import it in project and use it?

Documentation said i should install via npm and use it by a simple code in vue.js file, but it won't work, so i guess i should use app.js file to import it, but i don't know how should i make it work. Can anyone explain how i can use it in my project? i don't need a full code to bother anyone, just how should i import from app.js and how should i use json file to make it appear in project.

Here's the Github link : https://github.com/chenqingspring/vue-lottie

Comment: Did you read the [Installation](https://github.com/chenqingspring/vue-lottie#installation) and [Usage](https://github.com/chenqingspring/vue-lottie#usage) instructions?

Comment: @Phil Yes my friend, I've tried to import from app.js and vue file and didn't worked. i'm currently in learning process so i don't know more ways to try it.

Comment: Did you restart your server after instalation?

Comment: @AdamOrlov oh man... u just Saved me... Restarting worked... Thanks. Please post an answer to Accept it as solution. :)

Comment: That's fine man. Good luck ;)

Comment: @AdamOrlov Here's the problem, it only work when i use npm run prod.
it's not working on npm run dev or watch. what's the solution for working when it's on watch?

Comment: @Atlas-Pio Read the doc, check the issues, I don't know this library, I don't see your code, it's hard to guess man.

Comment: @AdamOrlov no problem my friend. gonna use npm watch-prod to make it work... Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in Development Mode.
Since i was using `npm run watch` , I thought it's normal like other npm packages but it wasn't, then i restarted with `npm run prod` and it's worked. doesn't matter if i use `npm run watch` or `npm run dev`. it only work when i'm using `npm run prod`.